# If I had an infinitely large paper, how could I draw an n-element karnaugh map for (n>6)?

Tags: karnaugh-map

I understand that k-maps become impractical after around 5 variables, and my textbook only describes them up to 6. However, out of curiosity, is there a general rule, method, or algorithm that I could use to draw a k-map for any given variable amount (20 for example), even if it would not be completable in a year. If it is impossible on two dimensional paper, is it maybe possible if I could theoretically draw in more in than two dimensions?

Comment: At that point, it's better to use Q-M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRAWING a large Karnaugh map is simple. Let's say you have an n-bit system where n is even. Then you simply make a square K-map, with M entries on each side, where $$M = 2^{\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)} $$ So, for instance, a 20-bit system would need a map with \$2^{10}\$, or 1024 entries on a side, for a total of 1,048,576 cells.

The problem is not drawing large K-maps, it's using them.

Comment: Oh, that actually makes perfect sense. So I assume that a engineer with infinite time could solve it simply as he would a 4-variable k-map, by recursively combining sets of squares which differ in value by only one bit? 

Anyway, this is what I came here for. Thank you.

Comment: @FabulousGlobe - Thanks for the vote, but you should be aware that the general rule is to wait 24 hours before selecting an answer. On the one hand, somebody might persuasively argue that I am wrong, or provide an even better answer. Improbable as that may be (grin). On the other hand, there's really no rush. The site will still be here tomorrow.

Comment: I actually can't vote in EE exchange yet, that was someone else. In the awkward case that someone logically disagrees with you, I can always transfer the acceptance.